# Typescript slows down solution build

Tags: visual-studio-2012, typescript, build-process

Before Typescript my entire solution would compile within a second. If there weren't any changes to the source code then it would complete the build almost instantly.

Now with Typescript installed every build takes several seconds. It just sits there and pauses.

I've only got six `.ts` files and four definition files. There's barely any code.

Is this normal? Is it possible to remove Typescript from the main build and only have it run when I save a `.ts` file?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this normal?

No. But we can't help without looking at the code (unless someone else has experienced it).

> Is it possible to remove Typescript from the main build and only have it run when I save a .ts file

You can have both or disable both. You can't have them partially.

Workaround. Move `build` out of the hands of visual studio into something external (like https://github.com/grunt-ts/grunt-ts disclaimer I am one of the maintainers). `grunt-ts` will only compile the files you save by default.

Comment: If I exclude all of the typescript files except one which has the following code... module mymodule{} then still there's the slow down.

Comment: If I exclude *that* file such that there's no Typescript in the solution then the build reverts to normal VS speed.

Answer (score 0):

There's apparently quite a lot of noise on the web regarding the speed of Typescript 0.9+. So I installed 8.3. Its a little quicker. But now the definition files are out of date. I think I might give up.

Fancy making a slow compiler in 2014!

Comment: That noise was for 0.9.0 as they rewrote it to support a few core language features (like generics). The speed was fixed in 0.9.1 (see the blog post http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2013/08/06/announcing-0-9-1.aspx) If you share your project (github?) I'd be happy to take a look at what's going on. It is not something I have experienced.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. There are people saying its slow even for version 1. http://typescript.codeplex.com/releases/view/118980

Comment: which version of resharper are you using (if any)?